# Getting LMCbutton to work right

Tags: javascript

Has anyone tried the [LMC Button](http://www.lettersmarket.com/uploads/lettersmarket/lmcbutton/demo_lmcbutton.html) before? I initially wanted to use ZeroClipboard as it is the most popular script around for copy to clipboard function, but it just doesn't work in my wordpress for some reason. LMC button works perfectly except for one little flaw - it can only copy codes that are shown on page load.

This doesn't make sense for me as I have a dynamically generated message I need to copy to my clipboard. Go to the link above to check out his demo and you will find the same thing. Change the input and click 'copy', it will not copy what you typed.

On further note, I cannot use ctrl-c as I need to add some codes into the text before being copied. Please don't make this suggestion.

Comment: i have the same problem. I don't know of a solution yet. :(

Comment: pls see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483224/editing-the-lmc-button-which-copy-to-clipboard/17891448#17891448