# Editing the LMC button which copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript

I have some problems with [LMC Button](http://www.lettersmarket.com/view_blog/a-3-copy_to_clipboard_lmcbutton.html) because of the way it is coded.

```
ShowLMCButton('Copied Text Here');
```

An image "Copy" is loaded when the page loads, with the words "Copied Text Here" being copied to clipboard when the image is clicked on.

If I do this:

```
var text = "New Text";
ShowLMCButton(text);
```

The words "New Text" is copied to the clip no problem, but the variable text have to be there on page load. There is no way I can change the words.

This is the ShowLMCButton function

```
function ShowLMCButton(cliptext, capt, js, furl)
{
 var params = 'txt=' + encodeURIComponent(cliptext); 
 if (!isNotEmpty(furl)) { furl = "clippy/lmcbutton.swf"; }
 if (isNotEmpty(capt)) { params += '&capt=' + capt; }
 if (isNotEmpty(js)) { params += '&js=' + js; }

document.write('<object width="40" height="20">');
document.write(' <param name="movie" value="' + furl + '">');
document.write(' <PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="' + params + '">');
document.write(' <embed src="' + furl + '" flashvars="' + params + '"  width="40" height="20"></embed>');
document.write('</object>');

//alert('file: ' + furl + ' Params: ' + params); // debug
}
```

How can I copy text that I type in a textarea/input textfield?

[Here is the demo of the button](http://www.lettersmarket.com/uploads/lettersmarket/lmcbutton/demo_lmcbutton.html)

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm having the same prob with changing values to copy :(

Comment: The method by mars-o works.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to make this work just now.

You just need to edit ShowLMCButton function, replacing 'document.write'

```
var flash_movie = '<object id="copy-btn" width="80" height="20">';
flash_movie += ' <param name="movie" value="' + furl + '">';
flash_movie +=' <PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="' + params + '">';
flash_movie +=' <PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE="transparent"><param name="scale" value="exactfit" />';
flash_movie +=' <embed id="flash-copy-btn" src="' + furl + '" flashvars="' + params + '" scale="exactfit" WMODE="transparent" width="90" height="20"></embed>';
flash_movie +='</object>';

return flash_movie;
```

With this, you can now call ShowLMCButton after the text you want to copy is changed.

You may need an additional function, e.g.

```
function update_me(custom_text){
    document.getElementById('binfocopytext').innerHTML=custom_text;
        document.getElementById('copy-binfo2').innerHTML=ShowLMCButton(document.getElementById('binfocopytext').innerHTML,'','','lmcbutton_copytoclipboard/lmcbutton.swf');             
}
```

and call this on e.g. onclick:

```
<b onclick="update_me('updated text');">whatever</b>
```

Comment: @Amitabh, it will just display the flash button inside any html tag you specify in .innerHTML.

Comment: Thanks! this really helped. Should be selected as the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

you can get the textfield/text field by

```
ShowLMCButton(document.getElementById('id of the element').value,'copy','',path to lmcbutton.swf);
```

Comment: i tried something like ShowLMCButton(document.getElementById('binfocopytext').innerHTML,'','','lmcbutton_copytoclipboard/lmcbutton.swf');

Comment: it didn't work... if the value of #'binfocopytext is changed on the fly. :(